# Oracle Concurrent Insertion

Tags: oracle, database-design, insert, concurrency

We have simple case like

```
Create table t1 (c1 number primary);
```

session1: `insert into t1 values (1);` **//session1 do not commit transaction**

session2: `insert into t1 values (2);`

Will Session2 hang/wait for session1 to commit/rollback transaction or not? 
As we are inserting different values?

If not then why, please shed some light on it

Comment: Session2 will **not** hang. Why don't you just try for yourself? This is _really_ easy to test

Comment: And the reason why is described in the Oracle Concepts manual. You should really read that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your case does not block on Oracle, nor should it. Concurrency is one the the major reasons to use an RDBMS instead of say, Excel.

But just to make it interesting, if you insert the 
**same value** in both sessions, it will then block.

**Session #1**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
-- do not commit transaction
```

**Session #2**

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
-- Since inserting the same value for PK, this blocks, as expected
```